# Not able to retrive all the tables attributes present in the database using databasemetadata

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to access `databasemetadata` to retrieve all tables present in it.
`getTables` should return a `ResultSet` of 10 columns.

When I try to iterate over the `ResultSet` to fetch all the column data, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

I retrieve the first 5 column data from the first row, then the exception occurs
when printing the 6th column, `TYPE_CAT`.

Relevant Code:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection1.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});
        while(rs.next()){
            for(int i=1;i<11;i++){
                System.out.print(rs.getString(i)+"  ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Comment: seems odd to start counting at 1.

Comment: @Randy: that's how JDBC works (everything is 1-based there)

Comment: Try to print out the actual number of columns returned by the driver using `rs.getMetadata().getColumnCount()`. Maybe you have a buggy JDCB driver which doesn't comply with the JDBC specs. Which DBMS and JDBC driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are either using a very old JDBC 2 driver, or the driver is not compliant with JDBC 3.0, 4.0 and/or 4.1 by not having all columns required by the specification.

Although JDBC specifies the columns the resultset (at minimum) should return, it is upto the driver implementer to actually correctly define the `ResultSet` and its values. JDBC is 'just' a specification and a set of interfaces, so it can not actually make sure - at runtime - that all drivers return all specified columns. There are certification tests but these require bureaucratic hurdles (opensource) or a hefty sum of money + bureaucratic hurdles (commercial), so not all JDBC driver implementers bother to test for compliance.

In JDBC 2 (Java 1.3) [`DatabaseMetaData.getTables`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) (links to Java 1.3 apidoc) returns only five columns:

> 1. **TABLE_CAT** String => table catalog (may be null)
> 2. **TABLE_SCHEM** String => table schema (may be null)
> 3. **TABLE_NAME** String => table name
> 4. **TABLE_TYPE** String => table type. Typical types are "TABLE", "VIEW", "SYSTEM TABLE", "GLOBAL TEMPORARY", "LOCAL TEMPORARY", "ALIAS", "SYNONYM".
> 5. **REMARKS** String => explanatory comment on the table

Whereas the JDBC 3.0 ([Java 1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) / [Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)), JDBC 4.0 ([Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)) and JDBC 4.1 ([Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)) defines 5 more columns:

> 1. **TABLE_CAT** String => table catalog (may be `null`)
> 2. **TABLE_SCHEM** String => table schema (may be `null`)
> 3. **TABLE_NAME** String => table name
> 4. **TABLE_TYPE** String => table type. Typical types are "TABLE", "VIEW", "SYSTEM TABLE", "GLOBAL TEMPORARY", "LOCAL TEMPORARY", "ALIAS", "SYNONYM".
> 5. **REMARKS** String => explanatory comment on the table
> 6. **TYPE_CAT** String => the types catalog (may be `null`)
> 7. **TYPE_SCHEM** String => the types schema (may be `null`)
> 8. **TYPE_NAME** String => type name (may be `null`)
> 9. **SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME** String => name of the designated "identifier" column of a typed table (may be `null`)
> 10. **REF_GENERATION** String => specifies how values in SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME are created. Values are "SYSTEM", "USER", "DERIVED". (may be `null`)

You might want to check if there is a newer driver available for your database.

Comment: Hi Mark I am using ojdbc14 jar only

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of the Oracle JDBC driver (btw ojdbc14 just tells you it is for Java 1.4, not which version of the driver it is). Otherwise Oracle really screwed up by not correctly implementing their - since they bought Sun - own specification.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use your value of 11, try getting the [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) and determining the column count to confirm your columns retrieved:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
```

From it, you can get column names and values and confirm what you are retrieving using the `getColumnName(int)` method.

Comment: ya I changed it, its working with out exception and printing only the first 4 columns, dont you think there are 10 columns in the resultsetmetadata

Comment: Ya I am able to retrive the column name of all the 4 columns correctly.My question is that why is it not returning all the table attributes, all 10 columns